# Can't pass 0 to NSRegularExpression options?

Tags: swift

I'm getting the error:

`Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments`

when I type:

`var expr = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "test", options: 0, error: nil)`

The error goes away if I pass a `NSRegularExpressionOptions` member...

#### How can I pass no options to NSRegularExpression's init?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Swift 2 `nil` is not accepted, and the error is no longer an output parameter (it is thrown), so it becomes:

```
var expr = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "test", options: [])
```

Comment: As sjs said, in swift 2 it is the correct way to do it. 
Don't forget the try catch
`var expr: NSRegularExpression?
        do {
         expr = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "test", options: [])
        } catch {
            print("invalid regex")
        }`

Answer (score 12):

Use nil instead of 0. NSRegularExpressionOptions is a struct so you cannot pass an integer in for that parameter. In Objective-C the regular expression options were done with enums which evaluated to ints.

```
var expr = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "test", options: nil, error: nil)
```

Comment: This is not longer valid in Swift 2.0. The `error` parameter has been removed. @vadian's answer seems to be the most correct way now.

Answer (score 3):

A value 0 for an enumeration type can be passed with an empty initializer

```
let expr = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "test", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(), error: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The .allZeros case is provided in many enumerations so you can specify no options.